# Python + GTK - How to suppress warnings

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

When I launch my python program, the terminal floods with:

```
rcGUI.py:331: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-label-select-on-focus after class was initialised
label1 = gtk.Label("Current tools configured:")
rcGUI.py:286: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-scrolled-window-placement after class was initialised
scroll_window = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
rcGUI.py:291: DeprecationWarning: use gtk.TreeView
infoList = gtk.CList(2, ["Tool" , "Version"])
rcGUI.py:291: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-button-images after class was initialised
infoList = gtk.CList(2, ["Tool" , "Version"])
rcGUI.py:217: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-can-change-accels after class was initialised
toolCombo = gtk.combo_box_entry_new_text()
rcGUI.py:217: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popup-delay after class was initialised
toolCombo = gtk.combo_box_entry_new_text()
rcGUI.py:217: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-menu-popdown-delay after class was initialised
toolCombo = gtk.combo_box_entry_new_text()
rcGUI.py:217: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-entry-select-on-focus after class was initialised
toolCombo = gtk.combo_box_entry_new_text()
rcGUI.py:217: Warning: Attempt to add property GtkSettings::gtk-entry-password-hint-timeout after class was initialised
toolCombo = gtk.combo_box_entry_new_text()
```

Interesting enough, my users running it in KDE do not get all those warnings (except the deprecation one), but those in GNOME do. So I think the easiest approach is to suppress all those warnings. I just haven't been able to find out how yet.

Comment: Related discussion: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/commits-list/2013-April/msg07206.html

Answer (score 10):

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

to unfilter:

```
warnings.filterwarnings("default")
```